# Send Form data in Email using PHP without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a contact section in my website. I want when a user submit the form all the data should be sent in email plus the page don't reload.

My form:

```
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" >
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" >
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile">
     </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     </div>

    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" name="form_submit">Send Message</button>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#send').click(function(){

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

        var varData =  'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&mobile=' + mobile  + '&message=' + message;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: varData,
        success: function() {
        alert("message sent");
      }
    });

    });

    });
</script>
```

Process.php

```
if (isset( $_POST['form_submit'] ) ) {
        // Do processing here.

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if ($name == '' || $email == '' || $mobile=='' || $message=='')
                {
         echo "<script> alert('please fill the field');
            </script>";
            exit;
            }


elseif ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'email@gmail.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Website Contact form'; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br><br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "mobile: ".nl2br($_POST["mobile"])."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."";
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
    echo "<script> alert('mail sent')
  </script>";
       exit;  



} else{ 
echo "<script> alert ('there is some problem');</script>";



}; 

    }
?>
```

The problem is the form is not using the code mentioned in "process.php"
How can I ensure the form data is sent in email? I have searched the previous answers but couldn't fix this.

Comment: Change the button to `type="button"`, otherwise it will submit the form and reload the page.

Comment: done but still email not sent.

Comment: I also recommend using an object for the `data:` parameter rather than concatenating strings. You're not properly encoding the strings if they contain special characters, jQuery will do it automatically if you give it an object.

Comment: can u please update my code?

Comment: If I knew what was wrong I would have posted an answer instead of just commenting.